# エラー　Use of '@import' when modules are disabled

Tags: objective-c, admob

AdMobを導入するためにGoogleMobileAdsフレームワークをプロジェクトに追加しViewControllerに

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
```

と記述したところ　Use of '@import' when modules are disabled　というエラーが出てしまいます。

調べてみたところ Enable Modules(C and C-Objective-C) を NO から　YES　にすればエラーが消えると書いてあったので試してみましたがエラーは消えず。

他に考えられる原因は何でしょうか？アドバイスいただけると助かります。

Comment: 開発環境はxcode7です。
使用言語Objective-Cです。

Comment: そのエラーメッセージで検索をかけたら本家のStackOverflowで[こんな記事](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272683/import-unexpected-in-program/21921045#21921045)が見つかりました。「使用言語Objective-C」と明記されていますが、Objective-C++(.mm)を使用されている箇所はないでしょうか?

Comment: 記載漏れです。 ファイルはViewController.mmです。  記事を読ませていただきました。 他の言語が混在していると起こるエラーというのはわかったのですが、いまいち対処法がわかりません。 .mmファイルを使う場合は@importという記述の仕方ではだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: Objective-C++の使用については十分ドキュメント化されておらず、私自身も確実と言えるソースは見つけられないのですが、エラーメッセージから考えるに「.mmファイルを使う場合は@importという記述の仕方ではだめ」と考えるべきでしょう。Build Settings中の「Enable Modules(C and C-Objective-C) 」と言う記述も「Objective-Cは含まれない」ことを言っていると解釈できます。代わりに適切な.hファイルを見つけて`#import`でimportしてやればよいはずです。きちんとした動作確認はできませんが、多分大丈夫という記事リンクと一緒に回答の形で書いておきますので、ご確認願えますでしょうか。

Comment: 「Objective-C++の使用」→「Objective-C++の **仕様** 」、「Objective-Cは含まれない」→「Objective-C **++** は含まれない」、5分を超えるとコメントの編集ができなくなるのですね…。

Answer (score 1):

コメントに示したように現在のObjective-C++では、`@import`でのModuleのimportはサポートされていないようです。

framework中から適切な.hファイルを探し出して、旧来の`#import`でimportしてやれば大丈夫のはずです。[こちらの記事](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572343/admob-sdk-ios-file-not-found)によれば、

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
```

でimportできるように書かれています。お試しください。

Comment: #import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
でエラー消えました！！
ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 0):

こちらより引用:
[STEP3: SDKの初期化コードを追加する | KARTE Developer Portal](https://developers.karte.io/docs/setup-react-native-sdk-v2#step3-sdk%E3%81%AE%E5%88%9D%E6%9C%9F%E5%8C%96%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

AppDelegate クラスが Objective-C++ (.mm) に書かれている場合に `Use of '@import' when C++ modules are disabled, consider using -fmodules and -fcxx-modules` のエラーが出る場合があります。
その場合はアプリケーションの Targets -> Build Settings -> Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags > Other C++ Flags に -fcxx-modules フラグを追加してビルドすることでエラーを消すことができます。

設定画面については、以下のスクリーンショットを参照してください。

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Objctive-Cなら、
`@import <GoogleMobileAds>`または`@import "GoogleMobileAds"`なのではないでしょうか？投稿時の記述ミスでしたら済みません。

それ以外には、左側のファイルインスペクターでプロジェクトを選択、メインビューのビルドセッティングで、Build Phasesをクリック、Link Binary With Librariesに該当フレームワークが含まれているか確認してみてください。

Comment: Objective-Cでも`@import`の場合引用符は要りません。`#import`と混同されているのではないですか。

Comment: ご指摘の通り混同でした。済みません